# How do I add libio to my session's PATH?

Tags: command-line

I'm going through the steps of setting up my Linux environment to use a SDR with Ubuntu 20.04.1. I see this as one of [the instructions](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio#how_to_build_it), but I'm not sure how to do this step:

> To build iio oscilloscope you'll have to make sure libiio directories can be found, one way to do this given it installed to /usr/lib is add it to your sessions PATH:
>
> ```
> /libiio$ PATH=/usr/lib/:$PATH
> ```

Well, just entering this gave me an error:

```
bash: /libiio$: No such file or directory
```

how do I add this to my sessions path?

Comment: `/libiio$` is probably just meant to denote the command prompt, showing that you are in the `libiio` directory when you execute the `PATH=/usr/lib/:$PATH` command (although fwiw adding the `/usr/lib` directory to one's executable `PATH` sounds sketchy to me - libraries have their own search paths unrelated to `PATH`)

Comment: thanks again for the feedback steeldriver; I've got PATH set up correctly now;

Comment: Deb-packaged version from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libiio-dev may be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda of agree adding `/usr/lib` to your path is kinda of weird but the correct way to do it would be from the terminal run `export PATH=/usr/lib/:$PATH` however that will only be good until you logout to make it persistent add that same line to your `.bashrc` file.  The first time you add it to your `.bashrc` you will have to logout and back in to make it take effect or source your file with the following command `source .bashrc`

Comment: you just described the only method I've ever used -  export + updating the .bashrc file; I'm always looking to learn something new though..thanks